# Faking DB methods in Golang

Tags: database, unit-testing, go, mocking

I'm trying to create a unit test for the following function that is making database calls internally using Postgres driver:

```
type DBer interface {
    Exec(query string, args ...interface{}) (sql.Result, error)
    Query(query string, args ...interface{}) (interface{}, error)
    QueryRow(query string, args ...interface{}) *sql.Row
    Prepare(query string) (*sql.Stmt, error)
}

type AppInfoCtrl struct {
    DB DBer
}

type Rower interface {
    Next() bool
    Close() error
    Scan(...interface{}) error
}

func parseRows(rows Rower, infos []AppInfo) ([]AppInfo, error) {
    defer rows.Close()
    for rows.Next() {
        var i AppInfo
        if err := rows.Scan(&i.Id, &i.Platform); err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        infos = append(infos, i)
    }
    return infos, nil
}

func (a *AppInfoCtrl) List() ([]AppInfo, error) {
    query := "select id, platform from appinfo where deleted = false"
    rows, err := a.DB.Query(query)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    appInfos := []AppInfo{}
    parseRows(rows, appInfos)

    return appInfos, nil
}
```

And my test looks like this:

```
func (f *FakeDB) Query(query string, args ...interface{}) (*sql.Rows, error) {
    fmt.Println(query)
    var rows *sql.Rows
    return rows, nil
}
```

However, after running this I get the following compilation error:

```
appinfo/controller.go:68:11: cannot use rows (type interface {}) as type Rower in argument to parseRows:
        interface {} does not implement Rower (missing Close method)
```

When I look at the source code, sql.Rows does implement Close():

https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Rows.Close

Any idea what I need to do here? Am I even taking the right approach to test List() here? I'm not particularly picky about testing parseRows() as it only contains calls to db.Rows, but I need to at least test List here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `DBer.Query` returns a generic `interface{}`, which the compiler cannot assume has any methods at all:

```
Query(query string, args ...interface{}) (interface{}, error)
```

Meaning, unless you use a type assertion, you cannot call any methods on the returned value. Perhaps it should instead return `(Rower, error)`?

The compiler, in effect, sees this:

```
rows, err := a.DB.Query(query)
```

`rows` is a `interface{}`. It could be anything. It could be an `int`. It cannot assume it has any methods at all. So when you pass it to `parseRows`:

```
parseRows(rows, appInfos)
```

Defined as:

```
func parseRows(rows Rower, infos []AppInfo) ([]AppInfo, error)
```

Well, it takes a `Rower`, but you're passing an `interface{}`, which is not guaranteed to implement `Rower`. Hence the compiler error you're getting:

```
interface {} does not implement Rower (missing Close method)
```

It has nothing to do with the underlying value, but rather the type of the variable. The variable is of type `interface{}`, which has no methods, and therefor does not implement `Rower`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I changed the type to Rower, but I got this error: *sql.DB does not implement appinfo.DBer (wrong type for Query method)
                have Query(string, ...interface {}) (*sql.Rows, error)
                want Query(string, ...interface {}) (appinfo.Rower, error)
That's why I ended up changing the return type to *sql.Rows. However, when I run my tests rows.Close() panics with this: panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

I need to figure out how to create a fake *sql.Rows that doesn't panic when Close() is called,

Comment: You'll actually have to mock it rather than just returning a nil pointer to the real type.

Comment: sql.Rows is a rather big struct. https://golang.org/src/database/sql/sql.go?s=71562:72284#L2539 I wish it were an interface. I'm scratching my head to figure out a way to mock it now.

Comment: You don't need to wish it were an interface. Just create the interface you need and use it in place of `sql.Rows` in your types. That's the beauty of Go's duck-typed interfaces - the implementation doesn't have to know about the interface.

Comment: @mohi666 it's actually simple, take a look at this: https://play.golang.org/p/57fhkok0kEN (fixed link). Using this your mock implementation of Dber can return a mock implementation of Rower, and anytime you need the real thing use the adapter.

Comment: @mkopriva Thank you. That would work too. I really appreciate your help and suggestions.